# Can't install gems with native libs on Mavericks (a.k.a. Travis call home)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I cannot get a number of ruby gems to install on my machine, they all fail with something related to compiling the native part, and I can't get any of the solutions to work.

I'm looking forward to the famed ruby productivity, but after a whole day of battling with these install issues I really need some help to get a database gem working so I can get started on RoR.

It first happened with mysql gem, but also happens with sqlite3, and even trying to reinstall ruby-debug gem.

OS: Mac OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks).

ruby -v =>

> ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]

rvm list =>

```
> rvm rubies
> =* ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
> # => - current
> # =* - current && default
> #  * - default
```

rvm -v =>

> rvm 1.25.24 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin ,
>   Michal Papis  [[https://rvm.io/]](https://rvm.io/%5d)

gem -v =>

> 2.2.2

I have an up to date Xcode 5.1
xcode-select -v => xcode-select version 2333.

I have installed again the command line tools using:
xcode-select --install

I have then tried a number of XCode commands from other responses including:
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/

I have tried multiple answers related to gcc and linking gcc4.2 to gcc using symlinks.

/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v =>

> Using built-in specs. Target: i686-apple-darwin11 Configured with:
>   /Volumes/Media/Builds/gcc-5666.3/build/obj/src/configure
>   --disable-checking --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++,fortran --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1 Thread model: posix gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)

An example failure is this one:

gem install mysql2

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing mysql2:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb checking for ruby/thread.h... yes checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in
> ```
>
> ruby/thread.h... yes checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
>   checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes checking for
>   rb_hash_dup()... yes checking for rb_intern3()... yes
>   ----- Using mysql_config at /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
>   ----- checking for mysql.h... yes checking for errmsg.h... yes checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
>   ----- Setting rpath to /usr/local/mysql/lib
>   ----- creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> make "DESTDIR=" compiling client.c compiling infile.c compiling
>   mysql2_ext.c compiling result.c linking shared-object
>   mysql2/mysql2.bundle ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'
>
> make "DESTDIR=" install ./install -m 0755 mysql2.bundle
>   ./.gem.20140427-52262-1rr56ob/mysql2 make: ./install: No such file or
>   directory make: *** [install-so] Error 1
>
> make install failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.15 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   /Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.15/gem_make.out

Any ideas anyone?

One post I saw hinted at problems mixing some 64bit and 32bit components of Ruby, Gems, etc. But I didn't see a fix, or how I should go about re-installing a 32bit-only set of components.

P.S. It looks like a certain "Travis" should try to avoid putting references to his own directories into the code:

> linking shared-object sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle ld: warning:
>   directory not found for option '-L/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'

UPDATE 1

```
echo $PATH
/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:.:/usr/lib/tuenti_tools/bin:/Users/andrew/bin:/Users/andrew/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/Users/andrew/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/andrew/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/andrew/android-sdk-macosx/build_tools/17.0.0/:/Users/andrew/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:.:/usr/lib/tuenti_tools/bin:/Users/andrew/bin:/Users/andrew/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/Users/andrew/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/andrew/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/andrew/android-sdk-macosx/build_tools/17.0.0/:/Users/andrew/neo4j-community-2.0.0-M06/bin:/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Comment: I assume you have the 64bit version mysql installed on your computer?

Comment: Did you try: `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local`  Answer comes from : `https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/19670`

Comment: Just tried that. No change.

Comment: I just fixed all the issues reported by "brew doctor" as I thought the one related to gcc-4.2 might have something to do with it. No luck. When I look at the "mkmf.log" file gem install leave behind when it fails I see it's using "/usr/bin/clang" which maybe part of the problem?

Comment: I don't have a `clang` directory. Did you create that? Have you tried submitting this issue with `homebrew` or `rvm` @mpapis is always there to help. I would submit your issues with those two resources and see what they say. I had a ton of issues when I updated to Maverick, but resolved them with the the searching through the issues on both the brew and rvm repositories

Comment: I'm assuming your path is set up correctly, for brew and rvm. Can you show what `echo $PATH` produces?

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'll get errors from `exten.conf` when dependencies and/or paths are out of wack.  First make sure that your paths are working as you'd expect and that ruby in the command line is from rvm:

```
# this should output the path to the ruby in the .rvm dir
which ruby
```

Before you try anything else, make sure your homebrew is up-to-date and healthy:

```
# cd to the homebrew dir, typically here:
cd /usr/local/Cellar
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

Before you start installing stuff, make sure your PATHs are loading right.  First, you want to load the homebrew bins first.  In your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file(s) you may or may not have a setting for the PATH, but make sure you have a line that fixes the order to something like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH
```

You just want to make sure that you're loading `/usr/local/bin` first.  Also make sure that you have the RVM function loading correctly in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Make sure all brew dependencies are aligned, and fix anything it may say:

```
brew missing
```

You’ll also want to check on the health of your brews, and fix anything it suggests (I know you've done this already, but there may be new issues after refreshing your local repo and cleaning up from the previous command):

```
brew doctor
```

Not sure how you "patched" the gcc issue, but homebrew is great for that:

```
brew install apple-gcc42
```

After all that, I can rest assured it's not an issue with your local homebrew setup.  I'd recommend using homebrew wherever you can for any native extensions (including mysql/postgres/etc).  If you've done so already, uninstall the brew and re-install it:

```
brew uninstall mysql
brew install mysql
```

If after all that you still get errors, try cleaning up rvm:

```
rvm cleanup
rvm repair
```

Then uninstall/install the failing gem:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2
```

Good luck!

Comment: Followed all of those steps, still broken. BTW for "rvm cleanup" and "rvm repair" I used the "all" option for both. The only "bump" on the road doing all of that is warning from "brew doctor": "Warning: Setting DYLD_* vars can break dynamic linking. Set variables: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH". Not sure how to fix that. I have this in .bash_profile "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH""

Comment: In case I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling apple-gcc42 (as it was already installed). No change. Also tried using this lib directory  from the brew installed mysql (/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.17_1/lib) in the $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. No change.

Comment: I removed the setting of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and in a fresh Terminal checked that silenced the "brew doctor" warning, which it did, but no change - so not related to that.

Comment: ah I've seen the DYLD* issues before.  It has usually been related to a path issue and how you're loading rvm and homebrew.  I updated the end of my answer with some possible fixes.

Comment: nope...got /usrlocal/bin before /local/bin and I already had the line to load .rvm into the shell (needed on Mac OS X). After removing DYLD_ stuff I get a clean bill-of-health from "brew doctor". Still fails exactly the same.... I think I'll try removing an reinstalling the XCode command line tools.

Comment: I've got XCode 5.1.1 and from XCode 5 it seems that the Command Line Tools are bundled with XCode.app again. Anyone else have that version and this working? I did reinstall the CLT, so not sure if that screwed things up...

Comment: I still am convinced this is a path issue.  I also just realized I left out the `/usr/local/sbin`.  Try making sure `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin` comes directly after your `../.rvm/...` paths, and then is followed by everything else.

Comment: Mac OS X - there is no /usr/local/sbin

Comment: To eliminate something I decided to remove jruby installation. That caused rvm to complain about path. I fixed the path, then uninstalled jruby. No change.

Comment: You're right about PATH though. I manually edited it down (some is set by the system before .bash_profile is even run?) to this "export PATH=/Users/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:" and then the install worked!!!! Now to find out what the source of the problem is!

Comment: Got it! The problem is having "/Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin" BEFORE "/usr/bin". This order works: "/usr/bin:/Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin". I think it's this line that's doing it "[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"". If you post an answer explaining that and how to avoid it I will accept as answer.

Comment: Here's my "fix, add this at the end of .bash_profile AFTER the rvm scripts "export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH". This changes "gem" to come from "/usr/bin/gem". Otherwise the "gem" from "/Users/andrew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/gem" is used and it FAILS. I don't know enough about ruby and rvm to understand the root cause of that....maybe my installation is not correct.

Comment: So your fix to the paths may have worked for now, but you're setting yourself up for headache down the road.  Typically you always want homebrew's bins to run first from `/usr/local/bin`, and typically you want to be using rubygems associated with the current rvm install you're using (hence it referencing the rvm gems first).  Anything in `/usr/bin` is generally managed by OS X, and can get messed with on updates from Apple (which is also why you should use homebrew wherever possible).

Comment: Yes, I can see the possible problems there. It only installs with the "gem" not from my current version!! But I have a lot to learn and have no idea how to get a working and "correct" setup. So, I guess I'll have to learn a lot and then tackle again at a later date.....